# Find location of a value in a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash list and I want to find when a user gives a value if that value comes after or before a target key in the list.
So for example I have the following list

```
my_list = {
key1 => value1,
key2 => value2,
key3 => value3,
key4 => value4
}
```

Then the user chooses `key2` then it has a target key that was chosen let's say was `key3`

So my function will check if `key2` comes before or after the target key, in this case `key3`.

If it was an array I would check which index the value is. But in a hash I am not sure how to do.

Comment: Not so long ago, Ruby hashes were completely unordered. No concept like "before" or "after". More recently hashes are somewhat ordered:  a Hash object presents its entries in the order of their creation. But that is about it. No index, or next, or previous.

Comment: Get the keys array using .Keys method, then use.index method to get index of the both key and then compare which index is greater to know the result.

Comment: If you need *dependable* ordering then use an array. Ruby hashes store insertion order, but if you ever modify this in any way, your ordering might shift in unexpected ways. You might only need to save a list, say `LIST_SEQUENCE = LIST.keys` and then you're good.

Comment: @steenslag _"not so long ago"_ – 14 years :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple sequence look-up table with almost zero effort:

```rb
MY_LIST = {
  start: 'Start',
  middle: 'Middle?',
  end: 'End!'
}

MY_LIST_SEQ = MY_LIST.keys.each_with_index.to_h
```

Now you have something that looks like this:

```rb
{:start=>0, :middle=>1, :end=>2}
```

Which means you can do this:

```rb
if MY_LIST_SEQ[a] > MY_LIST_SEQ[b]
  # ...
end
```

No need to use a linear scan each time you want to look something up.